# Unknown word (CssSyntaxError) in JSX File (react js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, eslint

I'm working on a React project and have run into an issue where ESLint is throwing an `Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)` when linting my JSX files. This error seems to be related to CSS parsing within JSX, but I'm not using any CSS-in-JS libraries or style-related code that should cause this error.

Here's the content of my `MyComponent2.jsx` file:

```
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Food from "./Food";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header></Header>
      <Food></Food>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.jsx: (same error at return keyword)

```
function Header() {
    return (
        <header>
            <h1>My Website</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <hr />
        </header>
    );
}

export default Header
```

Footer.jsx:(same error at return keyword)

```
function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; {new Date().getFullYear()} Your website name</p>
        </footer>
    );
}

export default Footer
```

Food.jsx: (same error at keyword const)

```
function Food() {

    const food1 = "Orange";
    const food2 = "Mango";

    return (
        <ul>
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>{food1}</li>
            <li>{food2.toUpperCase()}</li>
        </ul>
    );
}

export default Food
```

And here’s the error message I receive when running the lint script from my package.json:

```
    "resource": "/e:/Web Projects/Learning React/React js/my-react-app/src/MyComponent2.jsx",
    "owner": "stylelint",
    "code": "CssSyntaxError",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)",
    "source": "stylelint",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 10,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 10
}]
```

The package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "my-react-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.17",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.55.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.0.8"
  }
}
```

I’ve tried the following troubleshooting steps:

- Ensuring there are no typos or syntax errors in my JSX or any CSS.
- Checking the configuration of ESLint and any associated plugins.
- Looking for any accidental CSS within my JSX files.

Despite these efforts, the error persists. I’m not sure why ESLint is flagging this as a Stylelint error when I’m not using Stylelint in my project. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code of Header Footer and Food?

Comment: I’ve updated my question to include the code for Header, Footer, and Food components. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I'm seeing this in every file I open in vscode (react app); something wrong with packages?

Comment: Same here, I’m encountering this issue across all files, including those in my Node.js projects, not just in my React app.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue today -- every file was affected, even on new test projects with Vite and CreateReactApp. Have no idea what happened. Anyway, if you search for stylelint in VS code settings and deselect 'enable', it worked for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQJXk.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do you use VS code? I've got the same error, I've fixed by uninstalling extension from my VS code. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution! Could you please specify which extension you uninstalled to fix the Unknown word (CssSyntaxError) issue? It would be really helpful to know.

Comment: The stylelint (Modern CSS/SCSS/Less linter)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion to uninstall and reinstall the Stylelint extension. Unfortunately, this approach did not resolve the issue for me. If there are any other potential solutions or troubleshooting steps you could recommend, I would be very grateful to hear them.

Comment: You will need to totally remove the extension not reinstall it. or you can check any extensions that is related to linters.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've completely removed the extension and checked for any other linter-related extensions that might be causing conflicts. Despite these efforts, the issue persists. I'm open to any other suggestions you might have.